# Does a zero-length line with an arrow make sense? Is it a bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, best-practices

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle{1}
    \pnode(1;\i){R}
    \psset{arrows=->}
    \psline(R)
    \psline[linecolor=blue](R|0,0)
    \psline[linecolor=red](0,0|R)
    \psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,arrows=-,dash=2pt 2pt}
    \psline(R)(R|0,0)
    \psline(R)(0,0|R)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Does a zero-length line with an arrow make sense? Is it a bug? I hope it is a bug.
If it is not a bug, what is the best way to handle this case using a conditional macro in either TeX or PS level?

Apparently, this feature is also adopted by TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzpicture
        \fill[yellow] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,-1) -- cycle;
        \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,0);
    \endtikzpicture
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add an epsilon perturbation so that direction is properly defined.

Comment: why should this be a bug? If the _user_ defines an arrow then it is drawn.

Comment: @Herbert: Because it does not make sense. It will be better if the PSTricks core automatically does nothing for zero-length lines.

Comment: that has the user to be decide if it makes sense or not ...

Comment: @Herbert: If the line length with an arrow is measured from the tip of the arrow to the tail of the line then a zero-length line should be invisible. :-)

Comment: I guess this feature is provided for users who need to draw an arrow head only.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: exactly, eg for a vector field

Comment: @Herbert: Is it necessary to draw a zero-length vector field only with arrow heads? In my opinion, if we draw the arrow head for zero vector field then it will probably make the reader assume the magnitude of the vector field is not zero but too small to be drawn instead. It is dangerous. :-)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. The problem with TikZ will be that only `\draw[->] (0,0);` draws the arrow, even it is just a move-to. A more complicated case will be `\draw[->] (0,0) -- (.2,.2) (.5,.5);` (also, try `<->`). I guess someone has to test somehow if the last operation on a path is a move-to and disable the “start arrow”. Simple..?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Just testing for a move-to won't be enough, since `\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,0);` also shouldn't result in an arrow head.

Comment: @Jake You’re right, I didn’t mention the original problem anymore. I guess, your answer will cover most of the problematic cases.

Comment: @Jake and Qrrbrbirlbel: Should it be regarded as a bug?

Comment: @PGFTricks: Depends on your definition of "bug", I think. You might want to [post a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/?source=navbar) and see if it gets accepted.

Comment: @Jake: OK. Thanks. I will make a bug report later.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Did you make one? If yes, what was the feedback? Jake’s answer won’t work for the CVS version (with or without the new `arrows.meta` library) and such strange paths have even more interesting results (there is a non-non-zero-length path added).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I have not made a bug report yet. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `pstricks.tex` from  http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/ `\psLine` can have only *one* or *two* pairs of coordinates. Will later be on CTAN.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \pscircle{1}
    \pnode(1;\i){R}
    \psset{arrows=->}
    \psLine(R)
    \psLine[linecolor=blue](R|0,0)
    \psLine[linecolor=red](0,0|R)
    \psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,arrows=-,dash=2pt 2pt}
    \psLine(R)(R|0,0)
    \psLine(R)(0,0|R)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there another simpler, high level (as opposed to the low level with PSTricks core macro) workaround that I can digest and adopt for my future projects?

Answer (score 13):

In TikZ, you can avoid drawing arrow heads if the last segment of a path has a length of zero by patching the internal `\pgf@check@for@arrows` macro:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@check@for@arrows{%
  \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
  \ifx\pgf@startarrow\pgfutil@empty\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifx\pgf@endarrow\pgfutil@empty\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifdim\pgf@shorten@end@additional=0pt\relax\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifdim\pgf@shorten@start@additional=0pt\relax\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifpgf@drawarrows%
    \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\pgf@arrowpath%
    \ifx\pgf@arrowpath\pgfutil@empty%
      \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
    \else%
      \pgfprocesscheckclosed{\pgf@arrowpath}{\pgf@drawarrowsfalse}%
      %%% New stuff starts here
      % Extract first, second, second last and last points
      \pgfprocesspathextractpoints{\pgf@arrowpath}%
      % If the second last and last points are identical ...
      \ifx\pgfpointsecondlastonpath\pgfpointlastonpath%
        % ... disable the arrow head
        \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
      \fi%
      %%% New stuff ends here
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@check@for@arrows{%
  \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
  \ifx\pgf@startarrow\pgfutil@empty\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifx\pgf@endarrow\pgfutil@empty\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifdim\pgf@shorten@end@additional=0pt\relax\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifdim\pgf@shorten@start@additional=0pt\relax\else\pgf@drawarrowstrue\fi%
  \ifpgf@drawarrows%
    \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\pgf@arrowpath%
    \ifx\pgf@arrowpath\pgfutil@empty%
      \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
    \else%
      \pgfprocesscheckclosed{\pgf@arrowpath}{\pgf@drawarrowsfalse}%
      \pgfprocesspathextractpoints{\pgf@arrowpath}%
      \ifx\pgfpointsecondlastonpath\pgfpointlastonpath%
        \pgf@drawarrowsfalse%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\foreach \angle in {0,5,...,355}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=1.5,
        arrow/.style={
            -stealth, thick, line cap=round 
        }
    ]
        \fill [white] (-1.02,-1.02) rectangle (1.02, 1.02);
        \draw [gray, densely dashed] (0:{cos(\angle)}) |- (90:{sin(\angle)});
        \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
        \draw [blue, arrow] (0,0) -- (0:{cos(\angle)});
        \draw [red, arrow] (0,0) -- (90:{sin(\angle)});
        \draw [black, arrow] (0,0) -- (\angle:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```