# Arrow tips in TiKZ appearing where I do not specify them

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

In a simple drawing like this (I use `automata` library):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node
  distance=2cm,auto,initial text=]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20]
  \node[state] (a) {};
  \node[coordinate] (b) [right of=a] {};
  \node[state] (c) [right of=b] {};
  \draw[-] (a) edge node {a} (b);
  \draw[->] (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get a tip in node `b` even though I do not specify it there. I create an additional node (here: `b`) to have a segmented line, and I don't want any tips there. How can I get rid of that tip? Interestingly, if I put a star at the end of `-` as an option for `\draw`, I get both a filled circle and an arrow tip at `b`, but if I keep `-` option, and prepend a star to `->`, I get two filled circles at `b`.

I don't know how to mark a comment as a good answer, but the right (and the simplest) answer was among comments. I replaced `\draw[-] (a) edge` with `\path (a) edge[-]` and `draw[->] (b) edge` with `\path (b) edge[->]`. I also had to remove the global option `shorten >=1pt` which gave me still small gaps in lines. What I wanted to achieve was several lines going horizontally, and then converging at various angles (with an arrow tip at the end) at a single state. Thanks for all the comments and answers.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It's  `\draw (a) edge[->] node {a} (b);` if that's your intention

Comment: @percusse It's `\path[->, <and other options for everything including edges>] (a) edge[<local edge options>] node {a} (b);` See [Strange arrow mark with TikZ edge and anchors.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15567) — Reading the question better, the arrow comes from the last path. Up should just use `\path[->] (b) edge (c);`, (or `\path` with every `edge` really).

Comment: The tip at `(b)` comes from `\draw[->] (b) …;` which although only including a move-to operator, draws the arrow there. General rule: Use only `\path` with `edge`s. See [Strange arrow mark with TikZ edge and anchors.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15567) Also related: [Does a zero-length line with an arrow make sense? Is it a bug?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70186)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It's a pointer. And you can get away with `\draw` if required.

Comment: @percusse I don't understand “It’s a pointer”. And yes, you can get away by modifying `every edge` instead of using `->` at the `\draw`, but I think `\path[->]` is easier. This is basically the same as [the “bug” in this ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/258/#15fa).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are actually trying to do here? Why not simply using `\path[->] (a) edge (c);`? For what is that coordinate in the middle? Also: [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It means I don't know what you are correcting in my comment but it's a pointer to that edge also accept options and behave different than `draw`.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the tip at `node b`, first remove the `coordinate` option in that command. This will leave a short segment of space. Then use `calc` for calculaion of a new coordinate to fill the space by line.

[image]

Code: method 1

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=0pt, node distance=2cm,auto]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20]
  \node[state] (a) {};
  % method 1: remove the coordinate definition
  \node [] (b) [right of=a] {};           
  \node[state] (c) [right of=b] {};
  \draw (a) edge node{a} ($(b)+(0.2,0)$); % an extra line is drawn to fill the blank
  \draw[->] (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit (2014/01/23): Method 2

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm,auto]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20]
  \node[state] (a) {};
  % method 2: remove the coordinate definition and set outer sep=-4pt.
  \node[outer sep=-4pt] (b) [right of=a] {}; 
  \node[state] (c) [right of=b] {};
  \draw (a) edge node{a} (b);     % method 2: no extended draw.
  \draw[->] (b) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are expecting two-parts arrow:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node
  distance=2cm,auto,initial text=]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20]
  \node[state] (a) {};
  \node[coordinate] (b) [right of=a] {};
  \node[state] (c) [right of=b] {};
 \draw (a) [->] edge node {a}(b);
  \draw [->] (b) --  (c);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]