# Is zero-length line with an arrow in TikZ a bug?

Tags: tikz-pgf

## Question

Is zero-length line with an arrow in TikZ a bug?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->](1,1)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: PSTricks behaves the same.

I am trying to find whether it is mathematically useful (at least for me) but in fact it is not.

The direction of the arrow does not converge. :-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {6,5,...,1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,0) grid (6,6);
     \draw[->,ultra thick,red](45:1)--(45:\i);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In what way would this be a bug? It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @JosephWright: Why is it reasonable to you? Just a blank (nothing gets rendered) is reasonable to me.

Comment: There are two steps: 'draw a line' and 'add an arrow at the end of the line'. Just because the line has length zero, doesn't make it vanish.

Comment: @JosephWright: That is the bug. What is an arrow for in this case? :-)

Comment: It might be useful to be able to draw an arrow tip without any line. However, then one has the problem of pointing it in the desired direction! A couple notes: Just `\draw[->](1,1);` is enough to get the arrow tip. If you want to give it direction, there is this trick: `\draw[->](1,1)--++(60:1000sp)`. Interestingly, if you shrink the second dimension to less than about 600sp, the arrow tip reverts to pointing up. The exact limit may depend on the overall scale of the picture. This seems to me more a useless feature than a bug, but this site is not supposed to be about opinions.

Comment: @marmot: I think the author knew this bug but he/she left it as it is to speed up the compilation process. If he/she put a conditional statement before putting an arrow the compilation might take longer. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does a zero-length line with an arrow make sense? Is it a bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70186/14500)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In agreement with the comments [by Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468866/is-zero-length-line-with-an-arrow-in-tikz-a-bug#comment1180178_468866) and [Harald Hanche-Olsen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468866/is-zero-length-line-with-an-arrow-in-tikz-a-bug#comment1180211_468866), I would say that the answer to your question is

### no, it is not a bug.

Usually, a bug is some behavior that is different than what one expects from what is written in the manual. As pointed out by Paul Gaborit (**Thanks!!!**), on p. 183 of the pgfmanual there is a distinction between proper and non-proper tips. All you need to do is to add `tips=proper` to get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->](1,1)--(1,1);
\begin{scope}[tips=proper,xshift=1cm]
    \draw[->](1,1)--(1,1);
\end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the second arrow gets suppressed completely, which is, judging from your question and comments, the behavior you feel is appropriate. So all you need to do in your Ti*k*Z pictures is to add this style. (If you want it for all your pictures, just do `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={tips=proper}}`.)

Naively, you may think that Ti*k*Z could produce an error if the information is not sufficient, as it is if one does not specify the direction of the arrow. However, there is no error message. Rather, if there is no well-defined direction, Ti*k*Z will find one for you. I'd call that a feature.

Also, I cannot see the point of the animation. Clearly, Ti*k*Z (nor any other tool I know of) has knowledge on what happened in the previous frame (without further ado) . The last frame of your animation shows an arrow of length 0, regardless of whether the previous frames had arrows or ducks in. How is there a limit?

Comment: Because this bug is not so dangerous, let me call it a useless feature. :-)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy I dunno. What do you expect? You enter strange code and get a strange result. If you ask TeX to typeset `$1=2$` it will also do that without complaining. Yet I would not blame it on TeX if the equation is wrong.

Comment: If you buy a fried chicken, you can optionally get a pepper powder. Now you don't buy a fried chicken, should you get a pepper powder? :-)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy I am vegetarian. This is yet another example showing that it is good to be vegetarian. I do not have this problem.

Comment: If you buy salad, you can optionally get some dressing. Now you don't buy any salad, should you get some dressing? :-)

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Marmots generally don't buy food. Believe it or not, it is very hard for us to get a credit card approved. ;-)

Comment: @marmot The new (since pgf v3.1) key `/pgf/tips` and its value `on proper draw` may help...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks! Do you want to post an answer or may I add this to mine? (I actually really do not see anything wrong with the behavior.)

Comment: @marmot You may complete your answer.

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy Imagine you just need dressing (maybe you already have the salad in your garden). Wouldn't it be annoyingly if the clerk at the supermarket would refuse to sell you dressing because you are not buying salad as well? Imagine you already have some image and just need to add an arrowhead, how would you do this if you are not allowed to draw an arrowhead without line?

Comment: Eventually the bug has been fixed by `proper` value to fix the improperly designed. The end of comment.

Comment: @PaulGaborit and @ marmot Maybe it would be good to add an `tips=proper` answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70186/does-a-zero-length-line-with-an-arrow-make-sense-is-it-a-bug What do you think?