# TikZ: Incorrect arrow heads with edge node

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Why is the left arrowhead wrong, and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works fine if there is no edge node:

```
...
\draw[<->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
...
```

[image]

Comment: Try \draw (0,0) edge[<->] (1,0); . Or use tips=proper or tips=on proper draw, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469851/194703.

Comment: The first idea doesn't help because I lose the edge label. But `tips=proper` works. What's the idea here?

Comment: Also, if you write this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. However, I feel the credits should go to Paul Gaborit for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468866/is-zero-length-line-with-an-arrow-in-tikz-a-bug/468890#comment1180597_468890. If you want, I could add a (community wiki) answer when I am back at my laptop.

Comment: Up to you. My opinion is that your answer is a valid answer to my question and a non-trivial adaptation of Paul Gaborit's comment on that thread, and you deserve credit for the answer. But however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ways to resolve this. The issue is that an `edge` creates an independent path. As originally pointed out by [Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468866/is-zero-length-line-with-an-arrow-in-tikz-a-bug/468890#comment1180597_468890), one may use the keys `tip=proper` or `tips=on proper draw`, which are described in pgfmanual v3.1.4b on p. 188. IMHO the cleaner solution is to pass the arrow heads to the `edge`. The arguably cleanest way is to replace `edge` by `to`, which avoids drawing two separate paths. There are further option such as using `\path` instead of draw, but IMHO this defeats the purpose because the path is still there and may (at least in principle) alter the bounding box, say.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=original]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (original.north) {original situation};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,local bounding box=proper,tips=proper]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (proper.north) {\texttt{tips=proper}};
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,local bounding box=on proper draw,tips=on proper draw]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (on proper draw.north) {\texttt{tips=on proper draw}};
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,xshift=4cm,local bounding box=clean]
    \draw (0,0) edge[<->] node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (clean.north) {cleaner(?) solution};
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,local bounding box=to]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) to node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (to.north) {\texttt{to} instead of \texttt{edge}};
 %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm,xshift=4cm,local bounding box=path]
    \path[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0); 
 \end{scope}    
 \node[above] at (path.north) {\texttt{\textbackslash path} instead of
 \texttt{\textbackslash draw}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, is the issue here that `\draw[<->] (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0);` first draws a zero-length edge from `(0,0)` to itself, then another edge to `(1,0)`, so there's a sort of extra arrowhead? If so, why?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Because you start a path at `(0,0)` and then add another one with `edge`. If you use `to` instead of `edge`, the issue does not arise.

Comment: I see. I didn’t realize `edge` creates a new path. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define edge:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
every edge/.style={draw, <->}
                ]
    \draw (0,0) edge node {$a$} (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

or use the `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
every edge/.style={draw, <->}
                ]
    \draw (0,0) edge[<->, "$a$"] (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or combination of both suggestions.